# In llama_index t"AttributeError: 'ChromaVectorStore' object has no attribute '_collection'"

Tags: python, llama-index, chromadb

I am building the Streamlit app for the AI-enabled Google search. I use the chromadb to store the embedding and use Google's Gemini model.
In this First, I am using Google custom search to get the top URLs, scrap the data from that and make its embedding.

Here is my Code

```py
import streamlit as st

from llama_index.llms import Gemini
from llama_index.embeddings import GeminiEmbedding
from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, ServiceContext

from llama_index.readers import TrafilaturaWebReader
from llama_index.vector_stores import ChromaVectorStore
from llama_index.storage.storage_context import StorageContext
from llama_index import set_global_service_context

from googleapiclient.discovery import build

from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import chromadb

load_dotenv()

def create_embedding_store(name):
    chroma_client = chromadb.Client()
    return chroma_client.create_collection(name)


def setup():
    embed_model = GeminiEmbedding(
        api_key = os.getenv("GOOGLE_GEMINI_API_KEY")
    )
    llm = Gemini(
        api_key = os.getenv("GOOGLE_GEMINI_API_KEY")
    )
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
        llm=llm,
        embed_model=embed_model,
    )
    set_global_service_context(service_context)
    
    global collection
    collection = create_embedding_store("supertype")
    vector_store = ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection=collection)
    storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
    return storage_context

def ai_query_pages(urls, questions, storage_context):
    docs = TrafilaturaWebReader().load_data(urls)

    index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(docs, storage_context=storage_context)

    query_engine = index.as_query_engine()

    answer = query_engine.query(questions)

    if hasattr(answer, 'response'):
        return answer.response
    else:
        return "Error"
    

def google_query(query):
    GOOGLE_SEARCH_API_KEY = os.getenv("GOOGLE_SEARCH_API_KEY")
    GOOGLE_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID = os.getenv("GOOGLE_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID")

    num_of_links = 10

    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=GOOGLE_SEARCH_API_KEY)
    res = service.cse().list(q=query, cx=GOOGLE_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID, num=num_of_links).execute()
    url_list = [item['link'] for item in res['items']]

    return url_list

def main(query, ai_query, storage_context):
    urls = google_query(query)
    answer = ai_query_pages(urls, ai_query,storage_context)

    return answer

@st.cache_data()
def setup_app():
    storage_context = setup()
    return storage_context

storage_context = setup_app()

st.title("Llama Search")
st.write("Llama Search is a search engine that uses AI to answer your questions")

query = st.text_input("Enter your query")
ai_query = st.text_input("Enter your question")

if st.button("Search"):
    answer = main(query, ai_query, storage_context)
    st.write(answer)
```

This code is giving me the following error:
[image]

Please Help me to resolve this error.